# Trigger to update fields from one object to another (Relationship unrelated to each other )

Tags: apex, trigger

I have two custom objects:-

1.Product__c:- Fields - L1__c,L2__c,L3__c,L4__c,L5__c,Origin__c,Craft__c,Fabric__c,Zari_type__c

2.L1_L5_Master__c:-Fields - L1__c,L2__c,L3__c,L4__c,L5__c,Product_category_value_1__c,Product_category_value_2__c,Product_category_value_3__c,Product_category_value_4__c,Active__C

Scenario:- Update Active__c L1-L4 values with a combination of Origin, Craft, Fabric & Zari Type in the product object.

Pain points:- Origin, fabric, craft, zari type fields are there in product objects but the user can enter Origin, fabric, craft, zari type in the L1_L5_Master__c object fields like Product_category_value_1__c, Product_category_value_2__c, Product_category_value_3__c, Product_category_value_4__c so origin can be Product_category_value_1 or Product_category_value_2 or Product_category_value_3 or Product_category_value_4 and same for other fields.

trigger L1_L5_Master_Update_On_Product on L1_L5_Master__c (after update) {

```
if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isupdate){      
    L1_L5_Master_Update_On_Product_Handler.L1_L5_Master_Update_On_Product_Function(Trigger.new);
}}
```

public class L1_L5_Master_Update_On_Product_Handler {
public static void L1_L5_Master_Update_On_Product_Function(list<L1_L5_Master__c> L1_L5_MasterRecs){
List<Product__c> ProdRecs = new List<Product__c>();
ProdRecs = [Select Id,Cluster__c,Fabric__c,Workmanship__c,Zari_Type__c,L1__c,L2__c,L3__c,L4__c,L5__c FROM Product__c];

```
    for(L1_L5_Master__c L1_L5_Recs:L1_L5_MasterRecs){
        String masterKey = L1_L5_Recs.Product_category_value_1__c + L1_L5_Recs.Product_category_value_2__c + L1_L5_Recs.Product_category_value_3__c + L1_L5_Recs.Product_category_value_4__c;
        
        for (Product__c allProds:ProdRecs){
            String prodKey = allProds.Workmanship__c + allProds.Cluster__c + allProds.Fabric__c + allProds.Zari_Type__c;
            
            if(masterKey == prodKey){
                
                L1_L5_Recs.L1__c = allProds.L1__c;
                L1_L5_Recs.L2__c = allProds.L2__c;
                L1_L5_Recs.L3__c = allProds.L3__c;
                L1_L5_Recs.L4__c = allProds.L4__c;
                L1_L5_Recs.L5__c = allProds.L5__c;
            }
        }
        
    }
}}
```

Comment: The above may give you some hints.

Comment: @PhilW I understand your thoughts and appreciate the same however the suggestion which you have given doesn't help much.

Comment: I would have thought that the section "I need data from indirectly related records based on one or more input record fields" in that Q&A would be just what you need to identify the records to be updated...